# Send file generated by pdfkit from Flask

Tags: pdf, flask, pdfkit

I'm generating a PDF file using pdfkit. As I do it in memory, I use the following code:

```
result = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
```

result is bytes type, then I want Flask to send it to the client to be downloaded:

```
        response = make_response(result)
        response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
        response.headers.set(
            'Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename= 'report.pdf')
        return response
```

I take it on the client side (JavaScript, React) and try to save:

```
FileDownload(response.data, 'myfile.pdf')
```

But the file is always empty with weird title somewhere inside. I think the problem is with encoding but I can't figure out what exactly to do.

Comment: For those that come after me, I copied the code and it worked as expected with a valid pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and produced a valid pdf.

```
import pdfkit

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
  pdf = pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', False)
  response = make_response(pdf)
  response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
  response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename='report.pdf')
  return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```